# Size of EBP Register on the Stack?

Tags: assembly, x86

When the ebp register is pushed onto the stack (this is on IA-32 architecture) how many bytes does it occupy?

Comment: 32 bits. That's what the 32 in IA-32 stands for: the size of a register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In x86-32, all of the main registers (including EBP) are 32 bits in size, and take up 4 bytes on the stack.  The only exception that pops out at me are CS, DS, ES, etc -- and even those, IIRC, are pushed onto the stack as 32-bit values in order to keep the stack dword-aligned.

Comment: lol yeah I should have just thought about the question before I asked it. Thanks anyway.